# When does the interjection "absolutely" mean a negation per se?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my English classes, a long time ago, I remember the teacher giving examples of the interjection absolutely as a synonimus to 'not at all'. Example: Are you angry at me? Absolutely! Have you ever used drugs? Absolutely! Obviously, the intonation for this was the same of indignation, and not affirmative. 
Is this correct?

Comment: **Absolutely** means  "to an absolute degree, not permitting any variation or deviation". Something can be absolutely false or absolutely true.  *Absolutely no texting or phone conversations during the film! Mobile phones off, please.*

Answer (score 1):

Of course an overtly satirical or disparaging tone can negate an affirmative, but this is difficult to convey in text (at least not without adding some kind of imagery / visual cue):

> You: Did you like the movie?
>   Me (rolling eyes).  Oh yeah, *absolutely*.
>
> Me: Are you going to go out with him again?
>   You (making a face).  Oh, sure, *definitely*.
>
> Me:  Well, that was a fun party.
>   You (with a look of disgust):  Of *course*. I had a *great* time.

But I don't think this is exclusive to English.  Many (if not all) languages have the ability to make satirical statements that *mean* the opposite of what they *say*.

Comment: I really liked your examples! So absolutely doesn't have a negation meaning unless the person has a cinical tone implied. I was imagining a scenario where the person replies 'absolutely!' not in jest and satirically, but as in 'not at all!'. But this is not correct from your examples. Thank you.